# In Express and Node.js, is it possible to extend or override methods of the response object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, express

With every middleware, Express passes a `res` and a `req` objects. These objects extend the native ones that come from `http.ServerResponse` and `http.ClientRequest` respectively. I'd like to know if it's possible to override or extend methods of the response object.

For example, instead of `res.render('home', jsonData);`, I'd like to extend `res` with a custom method called customRender and use it like so: `res.customRender()`.

I'm not stuck at a particular problem or anything. I'd just like to learn how to extend native objects or, as with this case, object that come from 3rd party modules in Node.js

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The best idea would be to add a custom method to the prototype of the response object:

```
var express = require("express");

express.response.customRender = function() {
    // your stuff goes here
};
```

And this function should be accessible by every `res` object.

You can read the source code to see how they extend native objects. Basically they are doing prototype chaining:

**express/lib/response.js**

```
var res = module.exports = {
  __proto__: http.ServerResponse.prototype
};
```

And this object becomes a prototype of newely created response object (which comes from connect framework):

```
res.__proto__ = app.response;
```

(`app.response` is just an alias to `res` defined above). Note that `__proto__` property is a reference to the prototype of an object.

Be warned though. First of all `__proto__` is not a part of EcmaScript (it might not be available in other JavaScript implementations). Secondly: normally you would do inheritance with `Object.create` (setting `__proto__` directly on an object is a monkey patching and it is generally a bad practice, it may break many things). Read more about that here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: this doesn't work. from within the callable the context `this` will be the exported function instead of the `response` object.

Comment: You can also extend the constructed express instance in the same fashion (instead of the express constructor).
e.g. var app = express(); app.response.foo = function() { console.log('foo');}

Answer (score 3):

As [freakish answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18307732/5004549), you can add a method to the prototype. However, it won't have access to other members of the created object.
If you want to have that access, you need to go a step further. This is a full example:

```
const express = require('express');

const myExpress = Object.create(express().response, {
  data: {
    value: function(data) {
      return this.status(200).json({status: true, data: data});
    },
  },
  message: {
    value: function(msg) {
      return this.status(200).json({status: true, message: msg});
    },
  },
});
```

This way, you can create your express objects like this:

```
const app = express();
app.response = Object.create(myExpress);
```

From the response objects, you'll be able to call the `message` and `data` functions directly.