# Proper way to extend express Response Object using Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm currently working on a project that involves Typescript 3+, and express 4+ and node 8+. I'm trying to extend express's Response object to send HTTP status codes if an API detects an error for example.  I can't seem to figure out how to extend the Response object without using Middleware to define the Response extended function I want to add.  I would love to be able to just use the Response prototype to define the function(s) i want to add but i don't know or can't figure out if this is possible.  Here's what I've done:

projectA/declarations/express.extensions.d.ts:

```
import * as e from "express"

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Response {
            send100(): e.Response;
        }
    }
}

export {}
```

below is where i would like to define the prototype function definition like so but this isn't compiling...

projectA/extensions/ResponseExtensions.ts

```
import * as e from "express";
import { Response } from "express-serve-static-core";

Response.prototype.send100 = function(): e.Response {
    var response = this as Response;
    response.status(100).end();
}
```

and then finally consume...

ProjectB/Server.ts

```
import * as express from "express"

app.get('/getData'
    request: express.Request, 
    response: express.Response) : void {

    // yada yada...

    response.send100();
}
```

I can't seem to get the ResponseExtensions.ts script to transpile,  And the only other way i see to implement this is to run middleware where i define the function, but this will happen for every single request.  Are there options like I'm exploring or is middleware the only way to go?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Response` member of `express-serve-static-core` is only an interface, not a class with a prototype you can extend, so when you refer to `Response` as a value, TypeScript resolves it to an unrelated `Response` class that is part of the DOM API.  The prototype object you want to extend is the `response` member of the `express` module (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18307732)).  It isn't declared in `@types/express`, but you can declare it yourself:

```
declare module "express" {
    const response: Response;
}
```

Then in `ResponseExtensions.ts`, you can write:

```
import * as e from "express";
import { Response } from "express-serve-static-core";

e.response.send100 = function(): e.Response {
    var response = this as Response;
    response.status(100).end();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Matt McCutchen, could you please tell us how to implement your example? Where should be `ResponseExtensions.ts` imported? Where should we declare the module?