# Modify response body before res.send() executes in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In application which I currently develop, it's using Express. In my case I want to get response before it's been sent and modify it (for purpose of JWT). In this application, there is a dozen of endpoints and I don't want to create my own function like `sendAndSign()` and replace `res.send()` everywhere in code. I heard there is option to override/modify logic of `res.send(...)` method.

I found something like this [example of modifying](https://hackernoon.com/nodejs-express-js-manipulating-response-before-going-back-to-user-5e96ad8d84ca), but in my case this doesn't work. Is there any other option (maybe using some plugin) to manage this action?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to override and why? Are you adding data to response headers? Or is it something you want to wrap all response bodies in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Express and Node.js, is it possible to extend or override methods of the response object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304436/in-express-and-node-js-is-it-possible-to-extend-or-override-methods-of-the-resp)

Comment: I want to get response before it's being sent and sign body using jws.

Comment: @AlexandreSenges In possible duplicate there was answers about totally overriding function, but it's not my goal. I want to only modify body of it and use of original res.send() function. In other words I need something like middleware, but it should works for response object.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can intercept response body in Express by temporary override `res.send`:

```
function convertData(originalData) {
  // ...
  // return something new
}

function responseInterceptor(req, res, next) {
  var originalSend = res.send;

  res.send = function(){
    arguments[0] = convertData(arguments[0]);
    originalSend.apply(res, arguments);
  };
  next();
}

app.use(responseInterceptor);
```

I tested in Node.js v10.15.3 and it works well.

Comment: will it work for res.status(  ).json(  ) ?

Comment: I think `res.json()` ultimately uses `res.send()`, so the code snippet is expected to work for `res.status().json()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an NPM package called [experss-response-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-response-hooks) that provides response hooks.

You can register a hook in a middleware before all your other routes, that will enable you to change the response body when `send()` will be called.

For example:

```
const responseHooks = require('express-response-hooks');

// response hooks initialization
app.use(responseHooks());

// register a middleware that modifies the response body before being sent to the client
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // hook on "send()" function
  res.hooks.on('send', (args) => {
    args[0] = 'new-body'; // args[0] is the body passed to send()
  });
});
```